# Issue with configuring conTEXT to compile for Unrealscript

Tags: unrealscript, context-editor

I have been going through Rachel Cordone's Unreal Development Kit Game Programming with UnrealScript Beginner's Guide book and having an issue using the conTEXT text editor.
As per instructed through the book I have followed all the steps to configure it but it won't compile once I press <kbd>F9</kbd> - considering the last step to configure is to set the Enivronment Options/Execute Keys section. Here are the steps the book lays out (just that certain tab):

- 7) Now we are going to set up the conText  to compile code. On the Execute Keys tab, click on Add, then type `.uc` into the Extensions field that comes up.
- 8) Once that's done four keys, <kbd>F9</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>, will show up in the User Exec Keys window. Let's click on <kbd>F9</kbd> to make it convenient. Once clicked the option on the right become available.
- 9) For the Execute line, click on the button to the right of the field and navigate to out UDK installation's `Binaries\Win64` folder, and select `UDK.exe`. For Start In, copy the Execute line but leave out `UDK.exe`.
- 10) In the Parameters field, type "`make`" without the quote marks. This tells `UDK.exe` that we want to compile code instead of opening the game.
- 11) Change Save to All Files Before Execution.
- 12) Check Capture Console Output and Scroll Console to the Last Line...

Then all I have to do is press <kbd>F9</kbd> and it will compile - but it doesn't! It gives me:

```
No user command associated with extension '.uc'
Use 'Environment Options/Execute Keys' dialog to assign commands.
```

It seems it is not registering the changes no matter what I do (yes I clicked apply before saying okay but even still nothing). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions may be out of date. You'll need to select your ".uc" entry, hit "Edit", and change it to just "uc".

Also, if you use `UDK.com` instead of `UDK.exe` the console output will go directly into Context instead of going to a separate popup.